# How to load image by using webpack in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, webpack

Currently using web pack in .net MVC with Angular 2 development. Hope someone can identify and explain what I have done wrong in the config.

Problem.
Unable to load images (404), check in browser and only 2 images being loaded.

[image]

In my project images folder,

[image]

webpack.config.js

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

webpack.config.vendor.js

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|ico|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: extractCSS.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
            'angular2-universal',
            'angular2-universal-polyfills',
            'animate.css/animate.min.css',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
            'html5shiv',
            'isotope-layout',
            'jquery',
            'wowjs/dist/wow.min.js',
            'zone.js',
            './js/main.js',
            './js/respond.min.js',
            './css/main.css',
            './css/prettyPhoto.css',
            './css/responsive.css'
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]'
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
        , new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'images', to: './images' }])
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
};
```

_Layout.cshtml

[image]

Comment: I was having the same issue, I did it by placing the images inside the **ClientApp/media** folder, then just make the reference in your html like this `<img src="../../path/to/your/media/image.png"/>`, of course the src has to be relative to your HTML and will depend on your folder structure.

Comment: thanks for reply, will try